# If using AngularJS's directive as an object, then how do you implement an instance method?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

It is said that we can consider directive as an object, such as implementing a "count" widget on the web page.  Clicking on the left label will decrement the count, while clicking on the right will increment the count.

If so, can we implement an instance method for it, to do a `getCount()`?

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/htcvuer1/3/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <count value="1"></count>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .directive("count", function() {
    return {

      template: "click me: <span ng-click='dec()'>decrement</span> <span class='the-count'>{{value}}</span> <span ng-click='inc()'>increment</span>",

      scope: {
        value: "="
      },

      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        scope.dec = function() {
          scope.value--;
        };
        scope.inc = function() {
          scope.value++;
        }
      }

    }
  });
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Who would call `getCount()` and how would the caller get access to it?

Comment: is it true that in AngularJS, you normally wouldn't do such a thing?  Then how do you do good OOP? Just by having a controller or directive up above and share the value by 2-way data binding?

Comment: u can write a generic function like getCount(true/false){
   update the scope value here 
}

ng-click="getCount(true/false)" based on increment/decrement

Comment: you can use    var v = el.val("value = "+ scope.$eval(attrs.value)) to get value